# UIText View attributed string does not change

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, ios7, uitextview

I am trying set the attribute string font to 18. Here is code

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"We notice you've been pre-registrated here. Can you please confirm you are from %@?", visitor.company_name];

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];


NSRange range = [str.lowercaseString rangeOfString:visitor.company_name.lowercaseString];

[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0] range:range];

self.textView.attributedText = string;
```

This only increases the size of company name. The string size does not change from the original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line saved my life:

```
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line defining the string range.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,string.length);
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)];
```